# Visual studio _references.js autosync with additional external references

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

Is there any way i can get visual studio to use `<autosync enabled=true />` in the `_references.js` file for local files, but not strip any additional external reference i add personally? e.g. in the following file, autosync strips the react reference:

```
//_references.js:
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="build/client.bundle.js" />
/// <reference path="https://facebook.com/react-0.14.0.min.js" />
```

(you need to tick **Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Javascript -> Intellisense -> download remote references** for this to work without `autosync enabled=true`)

I would like to keep it autosyncing, but it always strips out the external reference when i add or remove a script. Is there any way i can tell it not to? e.g.

```
/// <reference doNotAutoSync path="https://facebook.com/react-0.14.0.min.js" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding them into a different file seemed to work for me:

```
//_externalRefs.js
/// <reference path="https://facebook.com/react-0.14.0.min.js" />
/// <reference path="https://facebook.com/react-dom-0.14.0.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../node_modules/react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.js" />
```